# How can I compile code that uses a .jar file class with BlueJ?

Tags: java, bluej

I am learning java with BlueJ, and recently I was given a .jar file called `Imagen.jar`. Apparently, what it does is return some pixel vectors depending on image file names given as parameters to it.

Anyway, I am supposed to make a program that will use a class called `Imagen`. Apparently, such class is within the mentioned `.jar` file.

Clearly, BlueJ won't compile if I'm using such class since I have not imported it or anything. But, I don't really know how to import such class in the first place.

I was given the following example code:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String arg[ ]){
      if(arg.length > 1){
         Imagen imagen = new Imagen(arg[0]);
         int [][] m = imagen.getMatriz();
         PrintWriter salida = null;
         try {
             salida = new PrintWriter(arg[1]);  
         }
         catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);   
         }
         for(int [] fila : m ){
            for(int valor : fila){
               System.out.print("\t"+valor);
               salida.print("\t"+valor);
            }   
            salida.println("");
            System.out.println("");
         }
         if(salida!=null){
            salida.close();
         }
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("Uso: java -classpath .;Imagen.jar Main nombreArchivo.gif");  
      }
   }
}
```

Which does not compile using BlueJ. However, as you can see, at the end it says that to use it, you have to type in the terminal:

```
java -classpath .;Imagen.jar Main myImageFile.gif
```

And I do it. But it keeps throwing me the same message.

So I am stuck right now:

- Why is the terminal line I was told to use not working?
- How can I import the class that is contained within a .jar file?

Comment: "But it keeps throwing me the same message". Please do tell us what the error message says.

Comment: @ReyCharles: The message is *"Uso: java -classpath .;Imagen.jar Main nombreArchivo.gif"*

Comment: In that case it seems it works correctly. You're just not supplying the program with an argument (which seems to be a .gif file).

Comment: You are of course right. I think the important part is that the error comes from the java program and not the JVM. Also, the code is a bit dubious. If `new PrintWriter(arg[0])` throws an Exception (note that it's `Exception,` not `IOException` or anything more specific) then it just prints the error and continues until the program eventually throws a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do the following once.

Select the menu option Tools -> Preferences.
In the resulting dialog, click on the Libraries tab.

[image]

Click the Add button.
Navigate to the folder containing jar file. Select jar file.
Restart BlueJ.

[Answer extracted from this place](http://horstmann.com/gridworld/gridworld-installation.html)

Comment: It works perfectly. Of course, it would be appreciated to have a deeper explanation as to what is going on and why, but thank you.

Comment: You are telling the IDE about the external jars it has to have in it's classpath so your classes can find them. The same thing you do in Eclipse when you set the build configuration of a project, adding you add external jars or relate your project with other projects.

Answer (score -1):

you need to import Imagen  class as it is being used in the main method.

Comment: But when I do *import Imagen;* BlueJ will tell me **" '.' expected "**

Comment: import <package-name>.Imagen. You should provide fully qualified package name for Imagen class.

Comment: Whether the class is within a package or not he has to import the class as it is not part of core packages. Learn about importing before down voting.

Comment: The class is in the default package (those which do not have `package foo;` in the beginning of the file). Classes and interfaces in the default package are always in scope hence you do not need to import them. In any case, how would you import a package in the default package?! This answer is just plain wrong. Have another down vote.

Comment: If there is a way to write the code that doesn't mean it is right. Are you encouraging people to not use packages? and this answer was given just by seeing the code in the question. How many people will write programs without package names? what if I have the same class name in another jar file without package? Any ways thanks for down voting and wasting your time in explaining what @Hot Licks already clarified.